# Command for Lightning

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I saw a friend make lightning come out of dispensers or they made it seem like it came out of dispensers. I know they used a command block.

How can I summon a lightning like that?

Comment: What is your question? How to create lightning? `/summon lightning_bolt` How they did it with a dispenser? No idea, that's not a property of dispensers, they must have done something with commands.

Answer (score 1):

From Java (computer) edition 1.11 onward the command is this:

> /summon lighning_bolt [pos]

Replace [pos] with an x value, a y value, and a z value. If unspecified, it summons by you. If you put a ~ in front of the values, they are relative to your current position.

In the current Bedrock Edition (formerly Pocket Edition and console versions) the command is the same.

<sub>[Source](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/summon_lightning_bolt.php)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
/summon lightning_bolt ~ ~ ~
```

This will summon it at your current position.

Enter desired coordinates instead of tildes (~) for an specific location, 
or enter a number directly after each tilde to position it relative to the player/command block.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE THIS: Please specify your question before asking. No one know whether it's bedrock edition or java edition.

As Stormblessed said which is used for both BE and Java:

> /summon lightning_bolt[position_here]

To spawn it on all players:

> /summon lightning_bolt @a

Bedrock formula:

> /summon @a lightning_bolt

Replacing **@a** with @p, @e will result in changes:

**@p** :will spawn on the nearest player

**@e** :will spawn on all entities

Comment: The `[minecraft]`-tag is not supposed to be used for the bedrock edition, you can therefor assume that it´s about the java version.

Comment: Thank for mentioning about, I'll fix it